# Wrap a loop to use HTTP pipelining

Tags: python, perl, curl, sh, keep-alive

I have a script that repeatedly makes X requests every Y minutes to the same server, and which currently doesn't use any pipelining / HTTP Keep-Alive, partially because each request has to be preceded by a header in the output.

```
#!/bin/sh -x
for k in $(jot 6)
  do
    while read i
      do
        echo -n $i
        curl -s "http://example.org/?param=$i" | fgrep result
    done <<EOF
some
uri
data
here
EOF
    sleep 600
done
```

What I want is to convert this to use a single connection to `example.com` for each batch, instead of establishing a new one for each request.

***Note that pipelining would be complicated by the fact that a header must be printed* with e.g. `echo -n $i`.**

**Constraints:** there may be zero or one lines from each request that would match the string we're trying to `fgrep` (so, the present script is also partially broken, because it wouldn't print `\n` if there are 0 lines, either).

I'm ideally looking for an `sh` solution, but I do have `perl` and `python2.7` available, too, if that wouldn't take too long.  (As well as `curl` and `wget`, plus all the other stuff that OpenBSD has.)

Answer (score 1):

A purely shell based solution will probably not work since you have to reuse the same TCP connection when doing keep-alive/pipelining. But, your current solutions isn't fully shell based either since it calls curl and fgrep all the time and if this is your understanding of a shell-solution than your shell could also call Perl and Python.

I recommend to just use the LWP (Perl) or requests (Python) libraries which both use HTTP keep-alive. There are enough examples out there on how to use these libraries, so there is no need to repeat it here. Apart from that behavior might differ between versions (like if HTTP keep-alive is on per default or not, and it is unknown which versions are installed on your unknown OpenBSD version). HTTP pipelining is harder but doesn't speed up the things much more than keep-alive in most cases (might for for really small requests). Also note that keep-alive does not magically speed up everything since it must be supported on the server side too. While most servers implement it, it is sometimes switched off to use less resources.

Comment: hm, i guess i just meant regular keep-alive, not really the pipelining.